# If two fighter's dice all come up with the same numbers, but one character rolls fewer dice, who goes first?

Tags: button-men

If Iago faces Changeling, and their results are:

- Iago: 1, 1, 1, 1
- Changeling: 1, 1, 1, 1, 1

[The rules](http://www.cheapass.com/freegames/buttonmen) say the following (emphasis mine):

> **To Begin:** Roll all of your fighter’s dice, and arrange your dice so they can be easily read. Players will now take turns. Whoever rolled the **single lowest number** will go first. If the lowest dice are tied, compare the next lowest dice, and so on until a starting player is determined. If all **numbers** are tied, the game is a draw.

What is unclear, is what happens when the characters have differing numbers of dice to compare.

- *Is it a draw?* Since you can't **compare** a die number to a non-existent die.
- *Does Iago go first?* Since an empty die (null die) has a value of zero.
- *Does Changeling go first?* Since they are the only character with a next lowest die, and all numbers are not tied.

I am leaning towards it being a draw, because you can't compare dice with a character that doesn't have a, "next lowest die" to compare. Has there been an official ruling in a FAQ, or in Tournament Rules? Maybe no one has ever had this happen and the question has never come up (it only happens 1 in 100+ million times)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It wasn't in the rules pdf, but it was within the [online rule book](http://www.cheapass.com/bpu/butnrulz.html).

> If all the dice are matched, the round is a draw. If one player has more dice than the other, and all the dice which can be tied for low are tied, then the player who has more dice goes first.